# DB managment- Enrolling students in class

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on a Student database management program. The database itself is mostly complete, however I'm having trouble figuring out how I should represent the classes a student has enrolled in inside the database. I have a table classes and a table students with each with its own primary key fields. So what would be the best way to do this?

Should I make a new table called enrollment list, where the fields are just a matching of the student and class id? Should I make new tables for every student that holds a list of their classes? These are the two ideas I've had, but I'm not entirely sure how they will work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a new table, i.e. `enrollment`

```
enrollment table
----------------
student_id
class_id
```

Put a unique key on the combination of both columns.

So if student `1` has the classes `2` and `3` then the table content would be

```
student_id    class_id
1             2
1             3
```

If you then want all classes the student `tom` takes then use the query

```
select c.name
from classes c
join enrollment e on e.class_id = c.id
join students s on e.student_id = s.id
where s.name = 'tom'
```